# How can Navier--Stokes equations have asymmetric solutions such as Karman vortex streets

Tags: simulation, navier-stokes, symmetry

The Navier--Stokes equations are axially symmetric, so with symmetric boundary conditions, how can features such as [Karman vortex streets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_vortex_street) develop?

I understand that in reality symmetry does never completely hold due to minimal fluctuations of geometries, densities, etc., but in the linked article, vortex streets develop even in numerical simulations

Comment: The von Karman vortex streets will not develop if you have a symmetry boundary condition at the center of your cylinder, but only if you mesh your entire cylinder. Furthermore, the Navier-Stokes equations are invariant by rotation (because of the symmetry of the stress tensor), but remember that they are a set of non-linear equations (velocity advects velocity), this can lead to all sorts of non-linear phenomena such as the vortex shedding encountered in the vortex streets.

Comment: @BlaB so the assymmetry in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBZDR0gMEEI develops because either the meshing or the boundary conditions were done asymmetrically?

Comment: No. in this case you have no symmetry boundary condition on the center of the cylinder (well circle). The circle is fully meshed. The instability develops because of the non-linearity of the Navier-Stokes equation. For a given Reynolds number, the solution without oscillations around the cylinder is unstable from a stability analysis point of view. Consequently, slight perturbations in the numerical solution (round-off errors, meshing, order of operations) start-off the oscillations.

Comment: A good example of stability analysis of a flow is the Rayleigh-Bénard instability. You can demonstrate via linear stability analysis that for a given critical Rayleigh number the absence of flow is unstable to any slight perturbation $\epsilon$. As such any type of rounding error in your numerical scheme is enough to generate this $\epsilon$ and start-off your Rayleigh-Bénard instability.

Comment: @BlaB I see the point that instability amplifies roundoff errors. But just to be sure, even the round off error should be the same if you use a symmetric numerical method (since computers do roundoff in a deterministic fashion), right? So the numerical method must somehow be asymmetric? Also what do you mean by "in this case you have no symmetry boundary condition on the center of the cylinder"? Do you mean "you have no symmetric boundary condition"? How do you know that? Why do you even need a b.c. at the center of the cylinder? do you mean the center of the boundary of the cylinder?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by a symmetric numerical method. Somewhere somehow you will always do operations in a certain order, whether it is when solving a numerical system by an iterative (or direct) solver or by looping over certain cell in a certain order. This leads to some roundoff errors which are on the order of machine precision (say 1e-16). You could have a symmetric boundary condition at the center of the cylinder by meshing half the cylinder and imposing slip on that surface. In this way you would constraint your space to half a cylinder and the instability would not appear.

Comment: Furthermore the Navier-Stokes system matrix is not a symmetric or self-adjoint system. The Stokes equations are self-adjoint, but this is not the case for the Navier-Stokes equation. The advection term makes them non-symmetric. They are invariant by rotation, but your discrete system is not symmetric.

Comment: @BlaB by symmetry I simply mean symmetry with respect to the y axis in the video linked to above. By symmetry of a numerical method, I mean also symmetry with respect to that axis. Take an explicit time stepper with a finite difference method for example. Since each entry of the matrix that represents the solution vector field is updated independently the round off error should be symmetric!

Comment: The Navier-Stokes equation (or at least the pressure part of them) generally are solved implicitely. If you had a perfectly symmetric numerical method where the order of the operations and all your parenthesis were balanced, then you would not get this instability without manually introducing a slight perturbation in your solution. In real life, you always have a source of floating point error which appears due to a number of reason and then propagates. Furthermore, I fail to see how you could perfectly mesh a circle with an ideally symmetric finite difference method...

Comment: That's all I wanted to reconfirm, thanks. (BTW, I don't understand the last bit. I never talked about PERFECTLY meshing anything, just about symmetrically meshing things)